# How to handle bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am creating a shell script which takes a filename as input so i am passing the file name like

A(01).txt

so suppose I want to measure the size of files it show the error

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I have just written

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 2 ] 
 then
    FILE1="$1"
    FILESIZE1=$(stat -c%s "$FILE1")
    echo $FILESIZE1
fi
```

I am already adding " " to handle space in filename but why the parenthesis are not handled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this script called `A` and you want to pass the file `01`? If so, call `A 01`. Do not call `A(01)`

Comment: You said you are passing the file name as `A(01)`?

Comment: We've seen two reasonable but inconsistent guesses for what you mean by `A(01)`. Please update your question to explain what you mean by `A(01)`. What is the name of your script? What is file name you're passing to it?

Comment: A(01) is a file name it could be any extension.

Comment: How are you invoking the script? `./yourscript A(01).txt`? That should be `./yourscript 'A(01).txt'` instead. It's not a problem with the script, but with the command line used to invoke it; you'd get the same error from `echo A(01).txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filename has special characters. Either you have to change the filename with no special characters OR if you don't have permissions to change the file name then pass the filename to the script like `<your_script> A\(01\).txt` or `<your_script> "A(01).txt"`